# Angular5: loading spinner before load page

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Is there way to load loading spinner

```
[`https://plnkr.co/edit/yhA0AwY9gzd0JsxhDouz?p=preview`][1]
```

and not on event (click) but on start loading page while application loading, i know that is tricky bcs directive of loading module can't be load before application, but if someone do it maybe in some other way. Thank you.

Comment: you could use the ngoninit function? or constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at -> http://akveo.com/ngx-admin/ , you can see the effect you're looking for.

The way they achieved it is by putting the code bellow `<my-app> Loading... </myapp>` in the `index.html` file.

Here is the link to their repo -> https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin, and the body part of `index.html` you're looking for looks like:

```
<body>
  <ngx-app>Loading...</ngx-app>

  <style>@-webkit-keyframes spin{0%{transform:rotate(0)}100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}@-moz-keyframes spin{0%{-moz-transform:rotate(0)}100%{-moz-transform:rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes spin{0%{transform:rotate(0)}100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}.spinner{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:1003;background: #000000;overflow:hidden}  .spinner div:first-child{display:block;position:relative;left:50%;top:50%;width:150px;height:150px;margin:-75px 0 0 -75px;border-radius:50%;box-shadow:0 3px 3px 0 rgba(255,56,106,1);transform:translate3d(0,0,0);animation:spin 2s linear infinite}  .spinner div:first-child:after,.spinner div:first-child:before{content:'';position:absolute;border-radius:50%}  .spinner div:first-child:before{top:5px;left:5px;right:5px;bottom:5px;box-shadow:0 3px 3px 0 rgb(255, 228, 32);-webkit-animation:spin 3s linear infinite;animation:spin 3s linear infinite}  .spinner div:first-child:after{top:15px;left:15px;right:15px;bottom:15px;box-shadow:0 3px 3px 0 rgba(61, 175, 255,1);animation:spin 1.5s linear infinite}</style>
  <div id="nb-global-spinner" class="spinner">
    <div class="blob blob-0"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-1"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-2"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-3"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-4"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-5"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting your spinner in the HTML page on the server side (i.e. index.hbs or whatever templating engine you're using) between your app tags?

E.g:

```
<my-app> 
  spinner code
</my-app>
```

It will show it while loading.

Answer (score 0):

I made **[this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/MTtfogPNenQvOtTVqkp2?p=preview)** using only CSS.

In your case, you won't be able to do this, since it is an Angular component. You need your application to be loaded to use your components !

What you can do is simply change my CSS (and HTML) code to suit your needs.

Have fun !

```
//Mandatory plunkr code
```